# How to compute a sum of products of array elements in Fortran?

Tags: fortran

Given `A(I,J,K)` with `I` = 1,2,3 and `J` = 1,2,3, I want to take the following sum

```
B(K) = c(1)*c(1)*A(1,1,K) + c(1)*c(2)*A(1,2,K) + c(1)*c(3)*A(1,3,K) + &
       c(2)*c(1)*A(2,1,K) + c(2)*c(2)*A(2,2,K) + c(2)*c(3)*A(2,3,K) + &
       c(3)*c(1)*A(3,1,K) + c(3)*c(2)*A(3,2,K) + c(3)*c(3)*A(3,3,K)
```

which gets cumbersome for large values of `I` and `J`, with `c(I)` and `c(J)` being constants for each `I` or `J`.

How do I write this code more efficiently? I think that a `DO WHILE` loop might be the answer, but I'm a beginner and can't figure out how to do it. Could someone please give me a hint?

My attempt:

```
DO K = 1,100
   J = 1.d0
   DO WHILE (J .LE. 3)
      I = 1.d0
      DO WHILE (I .LE. 3)
         A(I,J,K) = c(I)*c(J)*A(I,J,K) ! + ???
         I = I + 1.d0
      END DO
   END DO
END DO
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a do loop for J and I like you did for K. Accumulate the sum in B(K), which starts at 0.

```
DO K = 1,100
B(K) = 0
   DO J = 1,3
      DO I = 1,3
         B(K) = B(K) + c(I)*c(J)*A(I,J,K) 
      END DO
   END DO
END DO
```

Comment: If you're looking for efficiency on such short arrays, you must assure that the compiler has unrolled the inner loops so that all 9 products are calculated together.  This is equally likely to happen with the do loops shown above, or with a more compact notation using dot_product and sum intrinsics.  It may require options such as gfortran -O3 -ffast-math to promote in particular the use of simd instructions.  DO WHILE at best could match the performance of the alternatives.

Comment: Compilers may also need unroll options, such as gfortran -funroll-loops and possibly an unroll amount specification (if I understand correctly you want arrays larger than 3).

Comment: Given that OP is a beginner who had difficulty with nested `DO`, I think optimization options are a bit overkill at this stage.

Comment: Yes, @Ross. The efficiency the OP asked for is in writing the code, not in the code execution, which would be a much later step.